# Groovy .times {} closure

Tags: groovy, closures

Do we have someting for detecting the last iteration easelly like:

```
int num = 5
num.times {
    if (**IS_LAST_ITERATION**) println 'finally'
}
```

Find no info about that, but the possibility looks too obvious to be present

Comment: `(1..num).each { it -> ...` is arguably more readable than using times

Answer (score 2):

`it` or the explicit argument holds the counter:

```
int num = 5
num.times{ if( num - 1 == it ) println 'finally' }
```

UPDATE:

The iterations methods of Groovy do not provide arguments like `first` or `last` to the closure, only the iterated object(s) and index.

For your special case you could split the processing in 2 blocks and provide a custom handling for the last go:

```
int num = 5
( num - 1 ).times{ 
  doStuff() 
}

// now the last iteration
doStuff()
println 'finally'
```

Comment: In this case, I'd say `if (it == num) println 'finally'` but I am wondering is there a solution with no data checking?

Comment: `it == num` is never reached